# Best practice for setting a data source and delegate for a UITableView

Tags: xcode, oop, delegates, datasource

This question may not have a straight answer, but I am curious as to what others think. I have a UIViewController and inside that I have 2 objects a UIView and and UITableView. Each object as it's own custom class. My question is about the UITableView, what object should be the datasource and the delegate. Right now I have the UIViewController set to those rolls, but is it beset practice to set the object itself to be the data source and the delegate, maybe use the method awakeFromNib to set those 2 sources. Are both ways ok? I would think that setting the data and the delegate to the class that represents the tableview would keep that code apart from the view controller, which I would think would be a good thing.. but maybe not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question actually.

Look at the Controller as an example of the Mediator Pattern from the Gang of Four: it's mediating the relationship between the View and the Model. Most of the web world has gone to using binding of some sort, so you typically see model objects 'bound' directly to the view layer, e.g. a text edit field might have an expression indicating which field in the domain object it is editing, then the framework will provide the services of marshaling and unmarshaling that data.

In Cocoa, you typically don't do that: you bind to properties in the Controller, and those typically are then used to transform the underlying domain class. So for instance, if you make a storyboard and make a form and have a custom controller, now you want to edit the name of some entity, e.g. User, you would CTRL-drag from the edit box over to the source, it would make an outlet, which would then give you control not only of what appears in that box, but the control itself. Then you could add a submit button and CTRL-drag to create a method, for Save, and when that's clicked, you could update the underlying User instance.

Comment: Thanks Rob, so if I am understanding you correctly. The UIViewController should have an outlet to the table view that that is not only can be the delegate and datasource, but also control everything about the UITableView, e.g. x,y placement, animation if any, and things like that?

Comment: There are two ways to do tables in Cocoa: you can derive your controller from UITableViewController (if that's the main thing the view is doing), or you can make another more generalized controller a delegate that implements the various protocols. There are lots of examples of both.